# Create user and immediately execute a command with it

Tags: ansible

In Ansible I have an example playbook which creates a user and then stores the current directory as that user:

```
- name: Create a temp user
  user:
    name: temp
    password: "{{ 'thisismypassword' | password_hash('sha512') }}"
  become: true

- name: Store the current folder
  shell: pwd
  register: current_folder
  become: true
  become_user: temp
```

The issue I have then is that because of `become: true` the command executed by the second task is `sudo pwd` which requires the password of the newly created user. As far as I can tell I have no way of providing the password at this point. The error I get from Ansible is `Incorrect su password`.

I can not use the `user_become_password` variable because that is used by the main user (which creates the temporary user) and the server I'm working on does not allow users without a password.

The annoying part is when I execute everything manually it just works:

```
mainuser@server:~$ sudo su -l temp
$ pwd
/home/temp
```

So either I find a way to set the password to use for `sudo` dynamically or I find a way to omit the `sudo` alltogether when logged in as the `temp` user.

Tips are much appreciated!

Comment: `I can not use the user_become_password variable because that is used by the main user` <= you can set that var at task level.

Comment: I've changed the code to have `vars.ansible_become_password: thisismypassword` but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Why do you even want to get the current folder of a created user? If this is to get the home of the user, a better idea would be to ensure it is as you want It in the `user` task by adding `home: /home/temp`

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε it's just an example to verify I am indeed impersonating the temporary user. In reality I'm doing a lot more, obviously.

Comment: What happens if you manually connect to your target with the same connection user as ansible and issue a `sudo -u temp -i`?

Comment: @Zeitounator seems like my user is not allowed to execute '/bin/sh' as my temp user. Could this be the reason for my issues? The error I'm getting from Ansible is `Incorrect su password` by the way, I just realised I forgot to mention this.

Comment: Please review [ansible privilege escalation documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html) and make sure your configuration is correct all the way through (ansible configuration, inventory, playbook, tasks.....). Your error message clearly shows that you are not in a default configuration (i.e. the escalation method is `su` instead of the default `sudo` so you may have other changes affecting your current behaviour)